# R SVM alpha coefficients

Tags: r, svm, pmml

I am trying to recreate a SVM object in R from a PMML file, but am having trouble understanding how R stores the alpha coefficients. I am currently testing it on the iris data set and I generated a R SVM object with the command

```
library(e1071)
data(iris)
model<-svm(Species~.,data=iris)
```

and I am looking at its coefficients with the command

```
model$coefs
```

to get the following result

```
            [,1]        [,2]
 [1,]  0.0890967  0.00000000
 [2,]  0.0000000  0.14547777
 [3,]  0.8651998  0.94869969
 [4,]  0.0000000  0.13152589
 [5,]  0.0000000  0.27612243
 [6,]  0.8421469  0.45912899
 [7,]  0.4785865  0.00000000
 [8,]  1.0000000  1.00000000
 [9,] -0.4941407  1.00000000
[10,]  0.0000000  1.00000000
[11,]  0.0000000  0.63848160
[12,]  0.0000000  1.00000000
[13,]  0.0000000  1.00000000
[14,] -0.5471576  0.00000000
[15,]  0.0000000  0.52796849
[16,] -0.3772321  0.49504241
[17,]  0.0000000  1.00000000
[18,]  0.0000000  1.00000000
[19,] -0.1146136  1.00000000
[20,]  0.0000000  1.00000000
[21,]  0.0000000  1.00000000
[22,]  0.0000000  1.00000000
[23,]  0.0000000  1.00000000
[24,]  0.0000000  1.00000000
[25,]  0.0000000  1.00000000
[26,]  0.0000000  1.00000000
[27,] -0.7418858  0.10024212
[28,]  0.0000000  1.00000000
[29,]  0.0000000  0.60104219
[30,] -1.0000000  0.00000000
[31,] -0.8335805 -1.00000000
[32,]  0.0000000 -0.05538514
[33,]  0.0000000 -1.00000000
[34,]  0.0000000 -1.00000000
[35,] -0.6171002  0.00000000
[36,] -0.3564736 -1.00000000
[37,]  0.0000000 -1.00000000
[38,]  0.0000000 -1.00000000
[39,]  0.0000000 -1.00000000
[40,]  0.0000000 -1.00000000
[41,]  0.0000000 -1.00000000
[42,]  0.0000000 -1.00000000
[43,] -0.6609450 -0.78275762
[44,]  0.0000000 -1.00000000
[45,]  0.0000000 -1.00000000
[46,]  0.0000000 -1.00000000
[47,]  0.0000000 -1.00000000
[48,]  0.0000000 -0.52463404
[49,]  0.0000000 -1.00000000
[50,] -0.4928554  0.00000000
[51,]  0.0000000 -1.00000000
```

To my understanding, there are 51 support vectors and since R uses one versus one for multi-class SVM, there are essentially 3 classifiers (setosa v. versicolor, setosa v. virginica, and versicolor v. virginica) that each use a subset of these vectors. How do I know which coefficients in this coefs list correspond to which classifier (and which support vectors are used by each classifier)?

I saw that model$nSV tells you how many support vectors are in each classifier, but it does not specify which support vectors are actually part of the classifier. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, the way that libsvm (which r uses) keeps the support vector is a bit "cryptic". To understand better, let's use only Petal features, so we can visualize it later.

```
library(e1071)
data(iris)

fit=svm(Species~Petal.Length+Petal.Width, data=iris, kernel = "linear", cost = 10, scale=F)
```

The "alphas time ys" are stored in the coef matrix. To know how many SV relate to each class, you have to look at:

```
n = fit$nSV; n
```

In my run there are 1, 8 and 8. This means that the first `n[1]` (1) SV relate only to the first class. For the first `n[1]` rows the columns are 1vs2, 1vs3. For the next `n[2]` rows the columns are 2vs1, 2vs3. Etc. Note that some values might be 0. In my run, 7/8 values in class 2- column 1 are 0, since you only need 1 point to separate class 1 and 2.

If we want to extract the 1 vs. 3 separation planes, we need to do it as follows:

```
# class 1 vs. 3
# class 1 has n[1] SV, class 3 has n[3]
# rows of n[1], column 2 = [1vs2, 1vs3*]
# rows of n[3], column 1 = [3vs1*, 3vs2]
coef1 = c(fit$coefs[1:n[1],2],fit$coefs[(sum(n[1:2])+1):sum(n),1])
SVs1 = rbind(fit$SV[1:n[1],],fit$SV[(sum(n[1:2])+1):sum(n),])
w1 = t(SVs1)%*%coef1
# rho stores the b's, [1vs2, 1vs3, 2vs3]
b1 = -fit$rho[2]
```

Plotting (only class 1 and 3):

```
iris.norm = iris[, c('Petal.Length', 'Petal.Width')]
plot(rbind(iris.norm[1:50,],iris.norm[101:150,]), col=iris$Species)
abline(-b1/w1[2], -w1[1]/w1[2], col=4)
```

Image:

[image]

Comment: Thanks. Is `iris.norm = iris[, c('Petal.Length', 'Petal.Width')]`?

Comment: @chan1142 yes, I guess I forgot to write this. Not sure why I called it `norm`