# How to get coefficients and p values of SVM model in R

Tags: r, svm, r-caret

I wonder if there is a way to get all coefficients and p-values in svmLinear method from the `e1071`package. I tried `summary(modelname)` but that did not work.
Below is the code for my svm model with 10-fold cross validation:

```
library("e1071")
library("caret")
load(df) ## my dataset
ctrl <- trainControl(method = "repeatedcv", number = 10, savePredictions = TRUE) ## 10 fold cross validation
fitsvm <- train(Attrition ~., data=df, method = "svmLinear", trControl = ctrl) ##train model

summary (fitsvm)

Length  Class   Mode 
 1      ksvm     S4
```

I could get them with glm - logistic regression:

```
fit <- train(Attrition ~., data= df, method="glm", family="binomial", trControl= tc)
summary(fit)

                          Estimate   Std. Error  z value  Pr(>|z|)    
(Intercept)               3.424e+00  1.254e+00   2.731    0.006318 **
```

I'd be glad if someone can show me a way, thanks a lot!

Comment: svmLinear in caret uses the kernlab package. To access ksvm class info you can use the fitsvm$finalmodel@coef for the coefficients. p-values are not calculated.

Comment: @phiver thanks a lot! I didn't know about kernlab. I tried the code you wrote but it gives me "Error: trying to get slot "coef" from an object of a basic class ("NULL") with no slots".

Answer (score 2):

SVM does not assume a probabilistic model, so there are no Std-Errors or p. values.

You can get the coefficients, though. In the `e1071` package, the `alpha*y` are stored in `fit$coefs`, and the Support-Vectors are stored in `fit$SV`. You have to be careful how to extract them. If you only have a binary classification, then the coefs of the separation plane `b+w1*x1+w2*x2+...=0` are simply:

```
w = t(fit$SV) %*% fit$coefs
b = -fit$rho
```

If you only have 2d features, you can plot the separation-line using:

```
abline(-b/w[2], -w[1]/w[2])
```

It is a bit more tricky for multi-class. You can check [my answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67955967/6296435) for a detailed explanation how to extract `w` and `b` from the coefs and SV.